# aws client vpn - choice of certificate authority

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, certificate-authority

I am tasked to research on how to use aws client vpn service. After some reading I am a bit confused with the choice of certificate. It seems to use the client vpn, we will need to use aws **private CA**, instead of public CA because the public one is for domains. But the pricing of private CA is somewhat a surprise, [$400 for one CA per month plus any additional applicable.](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/pricing/?nc=sn&loc=3)

Please correct me if it's not private CA for creating the client vpn. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS Private CA, but it's very expensive. You can follow the [AWS Getting Started Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-getting-started.html) which uses a free "[Easy RSA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/client-authentication.html#mutual)" CA, which is fairly easy.

You'll want to be careful with this in production. From memory it gives you a shared certificate / key that multiple people use, which isn't good for security. For an enterprise you'll probably want to use the AD integration feature of Client VPN, which I haven't looked into in any detail.